# Rotation not executing when file size reaches certain threshold

Tags: rsyslog, logrotate

I have the following configurations in `/etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog`:

```
/var/log/syslog
{
        rotate 7
        size 1G
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
          invoke-rc.d rsyslog rotate >/dev/null
        endscript
}
```

From what I understand, I've set it up so if `/var/log/syslog` reaches `1G` in size, it will rotate itself. Also, the system will hold 7 rotations.

In testing, I did this:

```
cat /dev/null > /var/log/syslog
base64 /dev/urandom | head -c 999999999 > /var/log/syslog
logger -s "hello"
```

Then I did this:

```
ls -las /var/log/syslog*
976568 -rw-r----- 1 syslog adm 1000000072 Jul 28 19:11 /var/log/syslog
```

It's showing the file size as `1.000000728 GB` shouldn't it have rotated itself?

When applying the configurations, I did `systemctl restart rsyslog`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logrotate uses traditional units rather than SI units for K, M, G, etc. This means literally, quoting from the source code: `1024 * 1024 * 1024`, or 1073741824 bytes.

Comment: so i just need to declare it as `size 1073741824` correct?

Comment: @jk22721019 You already did! What you need to do is write more data to the log file.

Comment: Oh i see. lol haha

Comment: i did `logger -s "hello"` and now the size says `1073741883` for `ls -las /var/log/syslog` and no rotated logs...

Comment: i do see this... Jul 28 19:37:43 rsyslogd: unknown priority name "" [v8.1901.0]
Jul 28 19:37:43 rsyslogd: imfile: no files configured to be monitored - no input will be gathered [v8.1901.0 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2212 ]

Comment: @jk22721019 You know logrotate only runs nightly, right?

Comment: Oh. I see. So maybe i need to adjust the cron job to run every few minutes then, so it can pick up a syslog greater than a certain size correct and run the logrotate instead of waiting until night?

Comment: i thought by removing `hourly` or `daily` it would respond immediately. apparently not.

Comment: @jk22721019 You can certainly do that, but if you're really generating such enormous amounts of logs in reality then you should seriously consider (1) whether the logs are actually necessary, and (2) some other approach to storing them. Anyway, this has gotten far away from your question.

Comment: I appreciate the help. The only issue i have now is when i execute manually for testing purposes `sudo /etc/cron.daily/logrotate` it rotates perfectly but i cannot log any data to the new syslog file. i ammended to the logrotate script `chown syslog:adm syslog` and that is being finicky - it seems to allow writing after a minute or two of creation. Any ideas?